# Difference between SQL statements

Tags: sql, rpgle

I have come across two versions of an SQLRPGLE program and saw a change in the code as below:

Before:

```
Exec Sql SELECT 'N' 
         INTO :APRFLG            
         FROM LG751F T1 
         INNER JOIN LG752F T2 
           ON T1.ISBOLN  =  T2.IDBOLN AND   
              T1.ISITNO  =  T2.IDMDNO 
        WHERE T2.IDVIN   =  :M_VIN AND      
              T1.ISAPRV  <> 'Y';
```

After:

```
Exec Sql SELECT case 
                  when T1.ISAPRV <> 'Y' then 'N'                        
                  else T1.ISAPRV                  
                end as APRFLG                          
         INTO :APRFLG                                  
         FROM LG751F T1                                
         join LG752F T2 
           ON T1.ISBOLN =  T2.IDBOLN AND   
              T1.ISITNO =  T2.IDMDNO       
        WHERE T2.IDVIN  =  :M_VIN AND                 
              T1.ISAPRV <> 'Y'                        
     group by T1.ISAPRV;
```

Could you please tell me if you see any difference in how the codes would work differently? The second SQL has a group by which is supposed to be a fix to avoid -811 SQLCod error.   Apart from this, do you guys spot any difference?

Comment: I think there isn't any difference @KenWhite since the where clause is filtering out the `T1.ISAPRV <> 'Y'` which will always produce the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both examples of poor coding IMO.

The requirement to "remove duplicates" is often an indication of a bad statement design and/or a bad DB design.

You appear to be doing an existence check, in which case you should be making use of the `EXISTS` predicate.

```
select 'N' into :APRFLG
from sysibm.sysdummy1
where exists (select 1
              FROM LG751F T1 
                   INNER JOIN LG752F T2 
                     ON T1.ISBOLN  =  T2.IDBOLN    
                        AND T1.ISITNO  =  T2.IDMDNO 
              WHERE 
                T2.IDVIN   =  :M_VIN 
                AND T1.ISAPRV  <> 'Y');
```

As far as the original two statements, besides the group by, the only real difference is moving columns from the `JOIN` clause to the `WHERE` clause.  However, the query engine in Db2 for i will rewrite both statements equivalently and come up with the same plan; since an inner join is used.

**EDIT :** as Mark points out, there `JOIN` and `WHERE` are the same in both the OP's statements.  But I'll leave the statement above in as an FYI.

Comment: Look closely, the join and where statements are the same in both. The formatting is not clear, I adjusted it to make things more clear.

Comment: Good catch, reformatted mine to make it clear also.  Thus why I prefer leading `AND` / `OR` rather than trailing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a compelling difference, other that the addition of the group by, that will have the effect of suppressing any duplicate rows that might have been output.

It looks like the developer intended for the query to be able to vary its output to be sometimes Y and sometimes N, but forgot to remove the WHERE clause that necessarily forces the case to always be true, and hence it to always output N. This kind of pattern is usually seen when the original report includes some spec like "don't include managers in the employee Sakarya report" and that then changes to "actually we want to know if the employee is a manager or not". What was a "where employee not equal manager" becomes a "case when employee is manager then... else.." but the where clause needs removing for it to have any effect

The inner keyword has disappeared from the join statement, but overall this should also be a non-op

Comment: Well the first statement was written by me, the second by my lead developer who bashed me saying what i wrote was poor coding and it caused a lot of issues as i forgot to suppress duplicate rows. not a pleasent experience :P

Comment: If your lead developer is your superior, might just have to leave him to his wonky opinion. If he's your subordinate, he could do with a few lessons himself, as his sql has more issues Han yours does. In particular, slapping a group by or distinct on a query to suppress duplicate rows is a great example of poor sql coding.. "hmm, it seems when I joined these two ten-hours and-row tables together the resultset had a million rows! I'll just slap a GROUP BY on that to get rid of the duplicates.." - many times in my past I've admonished junior devs for writing bad joins causing Cartesian..

Comment: ..products (a huge waste of the database's resources/time) and then sweeping the dust under the rug by grouping the duplicates up to suppress them (another huge waste of database time and resources).. duplicates come from joins when the join strategy or relational design of tables is poor. It needs engineering out at source, not clobbering out at destination. Regardless of whether your lead dev is above or below you, his attitude is poor and his sql technique worse. Hopefully you don't have to work with him often

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just to use `fetch first row only` like this:

```
Exec Sql 
  SELECT 'N' 
    INTO :APRFLG            
    FROM LG751F T1 
      JOIN LG752F T2 
        ON T1.ISBOLN  =  T2.IDBOLN AND   
           T1.ISITNO  =  T2.IDMDNO 
    WHERE T2.IDVIN   =  :M_VIN AND      
          T1.ISAPRV  <> 'Y'
    fetch first row only;
```

That makes it more obvious that you only want a single row rather than trying to use grouping which necessitates the funky do nothing `CASE` statement. But I do like the `EXISTS` method Charles provided since that is the real goal, and having *exists* in there makes it crystal clear.

If your lead insists on `GROUP BY`, you can also `GROUP BY 'N'` and still leave out the `CASE` statement.